# Does a transgender male convert require a Hatafas Dam Bris?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, brit-milah

Suppose a transgender male (born female) who's undergone  bottom surgery and tattooing to make his genitalia look more masculine decided to convert to Orthodox Judaism.

Would such a person be required to undergo a [Hatafas Dam Bris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brit_milah#Hatafat_dam_brit) as part of their conversion process?

Comment: If there's no need for it Halakhically or medically, then doing so would probably be prohibited since it is forbidden to wound oneself. Though that might not apply while they are a non-jew.

Answer (score 13):

Here is an excerpt from Encyclopedia Halachit Refuit from Dr. Avraham Steinberg.

[image: EHR]

> Translation (my own): A women who underwent surgery to appear like a man, even if they formed for her a male limb, there is no obligation to do a bris on this limb, even if it is formed from her natural clitoris.
>
> In regards to a non-jewish woman that underwent gender reassignment surgery to become a man, it is not appropriate to accept them as a convert.

It appears that there is also no need to do hatafas dam bris, otherwise he would have mentioned it.

Comment: The responsa cited in note 85, saying that such a person should not be considered as a candidate for conversion (at all), can be found here: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43790&st=&pgnum=148