# Orthodox sources on transgender people converting?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

Looking for Orthodox sources on trans people and conversion… whether transgender potential converts should be accepted, any potential implications. I believe Sefer Dor Tehafuchot addresses this by saying a trans person who converts after transitioning might have the halachic status of the gender they transitioned to because they are like a tinok.

I also found this question and one answer but I’m looking for more sources

[Does a transgender male convert require a Hatafas Dam Bris?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103972/does-a-transgender-male-convert-require-a-hatafas-dam-bris)

Does anyone have the Sefer Dor Tehafuchot source or others on this topic?

Edit: I found the [Sefer Dor Tehafuchot](https://yctorah.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Edan-Ben-Ephraim-Sefer-Dor-Tahapuchot.pdf) source but I’m confused by the last half of it and the sources he’s bringing in as my rabbinic Hebrew isn’t great

לפי זה יש לדון באשה גויה שהפכה עצמה לאיש, ואחר כך התגיירה, שלכאורה יהא דינה כאיש לעין חיובה במצווה, שכן עד עתה היתה לה רק נפש והיא בדרגת בהמה שאינה מחייבת במצוות, וכעת כשהיא בצורת איש קיבלה נשמה יהודית. וכן יש להסתפק בהיפך. ועיין בשבת דאיכא מאן דאמר דמזלייהו דגרים הוה בהר סיני ופסקה זוהמתן. ועיין עוד בבמדבר רבה. ע’’ש. וראה למרן החיד׳׳א בספר מדבר קדמות שכתב: גר שנתגייר כקטן שנולד דמי. בחון לשון הזהב שאמרו ״גר״ שנתגייר ולא אמרו גוי שנתגייר, להורות כי זאת לפנים ממעמד הר סיני שקיבלנו התורה שם נמצא נפש הגר הזה הבא אחר זמן רב מאוד להתגייר, וכמו שאמרו חז’׳ל שנפדות הגרים עמדו במעמד הר סיני, ונמצא שמאז הימים נפש זו עמדה ונשא׳ת במעמד הנפלא של הר סיני אלא דאשתהויי אשתהי עד הזמן הזה, ושפיר אמרו גר שנתגייר. עכ׳׳ל. ועיין עוד בספר ניצוצי אור. ע’’ש. וצייע.

Comment: According to almost all opinions, transgender surgeries have no validity in Jewish Law, and sex cannot be changed. Someone who is transgender is in violation of the prohibition of cross-dressing, and thus would not be eligible for conversion. In addition, reputable conversion courts won't deal with someone whose personality seems to be unstable.

Comment: @N.T. If they're not Jewish, they can cross dress all they want.

Comment: Never heard of that work... [here's a link to it](https://yctorah.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Edan-Ben-Ephraim-Sefer-Dor-Tahapuchot.pdf) for anyone else that was curious about it

Comment: @Heshy I can't edit the comment, so I'll clarify that once they converted they  would be in violation, and Beis Din can't authorize a conversion of someone they know won"t keep the Torah.

Comment: Regarding the halacha sefer itself, it is legitimate and was written by a young Rabbi named Idan ben Ephraim who received semicha from the Chazon Ovadiah Yeshivah in Israel. The book carries haskamot from Ovadiah Yosef, Zalman Nechemiah Goldberg, Yosef Lieberman, Yitzchok Yosef, Asher Zelig Weiss & Shlomo Amar. As Rabbi Weiss writes in his introduction, due to the complexity of the subject & issues of modesty, it should not be addressed in a public forum.

Comment: Concerning your very limited quote above, it is not saying what you are concluding & only says that there are possible arguments on both sides of the subject. That even though the Jewish soul enters the body at the moment of conversion and is like a newborn infant, like you note; all the souls of the future Jewish converts stood at Sinai, soul dressed in some type of material body, similar to the entire Jewish people at that time, like is explained to Devarim 29:14 concerning 'those who stand here today and those who are not here with us today." The suggestion is that gender doesn't change.

Comment: @N.T. That’s your opinion. I’m looking for sources. Also Dor Tehapuchot specifically says it’s not crossdressing

Comment: @Yaacov Deane my post says *might have* not does have

Comment: @AS Your question says that “you believe” the author of the book is saying the person who converts after surgically altering their external sexual characteristics might have the halachic status of their hoped for gender because they are like an infant. The author is not saying that and does not suggest or support that view.

Comment: My sources are Rabbi Tzvi Hersh Weinreb in a lecture, and a rebbi in yeshiva in the name of Rav Ruderman.

Comment: @N.T Then post those sources, with quotations,  in an answer

Comment: @Yaakov Deane the Sefer does say that’s a possibility. Hence “Might have” in what I wrote

Comment: I heard them in person.